# stopPropogation not working consistently in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stoppropagation

I am working with 2 dropdown menus using `stopPropogation` to prevent the menu shifting up and down when items are checked and unchecked.

One menu works great but the other is still jumping up and down when checking and unchecking items, although I am confident that I'm using `stopPropogation` in the same way for both instances. I am wondering what I am doing wrong in the faulty dropdown menu that's causing this issue.

Working dropdown menu:

```
return (
    <div onClick={(e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }}> 
      <FormControl
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        className={classes.formControl}
      >
        <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label" align="left" margin="dense">
          Select Models
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
          label="SelectModels"
          value={modelIds}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) =>
            selected
              .map(
                (id) =>
                  deviceModelData.find((model) => model.alg_id === id).alg_name
              )
              .join(', ')
          }
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          className={classes.rootSelect}
        >
          {deviceModelData.map((model, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={model.alg_id} value={model.alg_id}>
              <Checkbox checked={modelIds.includes(model.alg_id)} />
              <ListItemText primary={model.alg_name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Problematic dropdown menu:

```
return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }}
    >
      <FormControl
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        className={classes.formControl}
      >
        <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label">Select Classes</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
          label={label}
          id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={classIds}
          onChange={handleClassIdsChange}
          renderValue={(selected) =>
            selected
              .map((id) => marketplaceModelClasses[id].original_label)
              .join(', ')
          }
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {allClassIds.map((classId) => {
            return (
              <MenuItem key={classId} value={classId}>
                <Checkbox
                  value={classId}
                  checked={classIds.indexOf(classId) > -1}
                />
                <ListItemText
                  primary={marketplaceModelClasses[classId].original_label}
                />
              </MenuItem>
            );
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know that it's the problem, but IDs must be unique or they don't identify anything. You're reusing them (at least in this example code), which makes for invalid HTML.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what element is passed as `e`?

Comment: Both instances of the example code are from separate `.js` files, is that still a problem regarding unique IDs?

Comment: If they end up in the same DOM, yes.